# Python pandas dataframe date and time combine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
   Date    Time
2011-08-03  10:52:30
```

The datatype for the 'Date' column is: datetime64[ns], for the 'Time' column is: object

I want to create a new column by combining the two columns as follows 2011-08-03 14:52:30 and then calculate the time duration (delta time) between successive times in the column. How could I combine these two with different data type and calculate the delta time?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
df
#         Date      Time
#0  2011-08-03  10:52:30

df.dtypes
#Date    datetime64[ns]
#Time            object
#dtype: object
```

Format the *Date* column as string, add it with *Time* column and then convert it back to *datetime*:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " " + df.Time)

df.dtypes
#Date        datetime64[ns]
#Time                object
#DateTime    datetime64[ns]
#dtype: object

df
#          Date     Time               DateTime
#0  2011-08-03  10:52:30    2011-08-03 10:52:30
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this one. However, the concatenation part always has the following error: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.time found

Comment: Problem solved when I add .map(str) to @Psidom answer. Thx!

Comment: ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2018-01-01 8-33-39')

Answer (score 0):

Simplier is use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Time']))
<class 'str'>

df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
print (df)
        Date      Time            DateTime
0 2011-08-03  10:52:30 2011-08-03 10:52:30
```

But if `type` of column `Time` is `datetime.time` add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'Time']))
<class 'datetime.time'>

df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
print (df)
        Date      Time            DateTime
0 2011-08-03  10:52:30 2011-08-03 10:52:30
```